# How to pass a string (list of defaults) to backbone from php using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, backbone.js

I am trying to use ajax between php and backbone, I am doing this to be able to extend the list using do_action without the need to modify it directly in backbone.

I can't actually explain but the example below might give you an idea on what I want to achieve..

```
wp_localize_script( 'main_js', 'custom_ajax', array(
'list_model_defaults_from_php'  => function_for_model_defaults;
);

function function_for_model_defaults(){
echo"
{ 'title' : 'First Title', 'field' : 'first_field'},
{ 'title' : 'Second Title', 'field' : 'second_field'},
{ 'title' : 'Third Title', 'field' : 'third_field'}
";
}
```

and then in backbone  all I need to do is:

```
MDefaults.Layout = Backbone.Model.extend( {
        defaults: {modules : [custom_ajax.list_model_defaults_from_php],
            views : []},
```

Is this logical?

Comment: What happens when you log the output of your function to the console? Also, why don't you use json_encode() for the output?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried json_encode and I neded to use str_replace to change " to ' but no progress